# Need help adding values to list

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a table called confiog.datalist that looks like this:

```
DBNAME | SCHEMANAME | TABLENAME | order
DatabaseA | staging | customers | 1
DatabaseB | conversion | * | 2
DatabaseC | fact | *truck | 3
```

Both databases reside on the same server.
`DatabaseB` has 3 tables in schema `conversion`: `teacher`, `classroom`, `student`
`DatabaseC` has 100 tables in schema `fact` of which two with truck in the name: `privatetruck`, `companytruck`

What I want is to create a dataset (Powershell) that contains the following

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseA.staging.customer
SELECT * FROM DatabaseB.staging.teacher
SELECT * FROM DatabaseB.staging.classroom
SELECT * FROM DatabaseB.staging.student
SELECT * FROM DatabaseC.fact.privatetruck
SELECT * FROM DatabaseC.fact.companytruck
```

I will be looping through this dataset to execute these queries.

I do know how to get `SELECT * FROM DatabaseA.staging.customer` and put that in a dataset.
I do know how to get all the `other SELECT statements` but I do not know how  to add all these statements to the same dataset ($FinalList)...

Below the code I have so far. The only issue here is that I do not know how to create #FinalList and add records to it... The part about executing the queries once they are in $FinalList is already done.

```
# Get variables
$dataSource = $args[0]
$database = $args[1]
$destinationfolder = $args[2]

#Create Connection
$auth = "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$connectionString = "Provider=sqloledb; " + "Data Source=$dataSource; " + "Initial Catalog=$database; " +"$auth; "
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $connectionString

#Read [config].[datalist] and insert in $tblDataList, fill $rowsInDatalist
$sql = "SELECT 
        row_number() OVER(ORDER BY [ORDER]) as [Order]
        ,replace(replace([tablename],'[',''),']','') AS TableName_Org
        ,replace(replace([dbname],'[',''),']','') AS DBName
        ,replace(replace([schemaname],'[',''),']','') AS SchemaName
        ,replace(replace([tablename],'[',''),']','') AS TableName
        ,replace(replace(replace([tablename],'[',''),']',''),'*','ALL_'+upper(replace(replace([schemaname],'[',''),']',''))) as [FileName]
        , 'SELECT  * FROM ' + quotename(replace(replace([dbname],'[',''),']',''))+'.'+
        quotename(replace(replace([schemaname],'[',''),']',''))+'.'+
        quotename(replace(replace([tablename],'[',''),']','')) AS SelectQuery
        from [config].[datalist]
        order by [order]"
$command = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand $sql,$connection
$connection.Open()
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $command
$tblDataList = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
[void] $adapter.Fill($tblDataList)
$connection.Close()
$rowsInDatalist=($tblDataList.Tables | Select-Object -Expand Rows)


#start looping through the results of the list I got
$i=0
foreach ($row in $rowsInDatalist) 
{

# I guess I should create the object here to fill it with results? This object could be called $FinalList


    if(-NOT $row.TableName_Org[$i] -match "\`*") # checking if there is a wildcard in the tablename
    {

     #excute following query and add results to $FinalList:
     $sql = "SELECT 'SELECT  * FROM ' + quotename(replace(replace(s.name,'[',''),']',''))+'.'+quotename(replace(replace(t.name,'[',''),']','')) as SelectFullSchema
            FROM sys.schemas s
            INNER JOIN sys.tables t on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
            WHERE s.name like '%' "+ $row.SchemaName[$i] + "'%' and t.name like '%' "+ $row.TableName[$i] + "'%'"
  
        
    }
    else { 

            # get $row.SelectQuery[$i] and add results to $FinalList:

    }

#execute all  queries from $FinalList

$i++
}
```

Comment: `UNION ALL`? But that only works if the columns are the same. You can't combine queries if the columns are different.

Comment: That is an idea!

Comment: Actually solved in such a way that SQL delivered the list. I am intimately familiar with SQL. That way I did not need to build complexity in Powershell :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually solved in such a way that SQL delivered the list. I am intimately familiar with SQL. That way I did not need to build complexity in Powershell :